# jQuery PHP only works with 3 parameters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Heyho,

I have a problem with the following code. I took the example from here: http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-a-row-in-jquery-flexigrid-using-php-and-mysql/ and only removed the "age" option.
But after the removal, I am no longer able to add records to my database via the form. If I add the record manually (with phpMyAdmin) I am able to edit the records via the webpage.

Maybe someone could figure out where the mistake is...

This is my code:

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Bootgrid example with add,edit and delete using PHP,MySQL and AJAX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="dist/jquery.bootgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="dist/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Simple Bootgrid example with add,edit and delete using PHP,MySQL and AJAX</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="well clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="command-add" data-row-id="0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Record</button></div></div>
        <table id="employee_grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" width="60%" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="bootgrid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Empid</th>
                    <th data-column-id="employee_name">Name</th>
                    <th data-column-id="employee_salary">Salary</th>
                    <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="add_model" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="frm_add">
                <input type="hidden" value="add" name="action" id="action">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary"/>
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="edit_model" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="frm_edit">
                <input type="hidden" value="edit" name="action" id="action">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="edit_id" id="edit_id">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_name" name="edit_name"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_salary" name="edit_salary"/>
                  </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#employee_grid").bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        rowSelect: true,
        post: function ()
        {
            /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
            return {
                id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
            };
        },

        url: "response.php",
        formatters: {
                "commands": function(column, row)
                {
                    return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " + 
                        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
                }
            }
   }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
{
    /* Executes after data is loaded and rendered */
    grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e)
    {
        //alert("You pressed edit on row: " + $(this).data("row-id"));
            var ele =$(this).parent();
            var g_id = $(this).parent().siblings(':first').html();
            var g_name = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html();
console.log(g_id);
                    console.log(g_name);

        //console.log(grid.data());//
        $('#edit_model').modal('show');
                    if($(this).data("row-id") >0) {

                                // collect the data
                                $('#edit_id').val(ele.siblings(':first').html()); // in case we're changing the key
                                $('#edit_name').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html());
                                $('#edit_salary').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(3)').html());

                    } else {
                     alert('Now row selected! First select row, then click edit button');
                    }
    }).end().find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e)
    {

        var conf = confirm('Delete ' + $(this).data("row-id") + ' items?');
                    alert(conf);
                    if(conf){
                                $.post('response.php', { id: $(this).data("row-id"), action:'delete'}
                                    , function(){
                                        // when ajax returns (callback), 
                                        $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
                                }); 
                                //$(this).parent('tr').remove();
                                //$("#employee_grid").bootgrid('remove', $(this).data("row-id"))
                    }
    });
});

function ajaxAction(action) {
                data = $("#frm_"+action).serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "response.php",  
                  data: data,
                  dataType: "json",       
                  success: function(response)  
                  {
                    $('#'+action+'_model').modal('hide');
                    $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
                  }   
                });
            }

            $( "#command-add" ).click(function() {
              $('#add_model').modal('show');
            });
            $( "#btn_add" ).click(function() {
              ajaxAction('add');
            });
            $( "#btn_edit" ).click(function() {
              ajaxAction('edit');
            });
});
</script>
```

response.php

```
<?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection.php");

    $db = new dbObj();
    $connString =  $db->getConnstring();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    $action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';
    $empCls = new Employee($connString);

    switch($action) {
     case 'add':
        $empCls->insertEmployee($params);
     break;
     case 'edit':
        $empCls->updateEmployee($params);
     break;
     case 'delete':
        $empCls->deleteEmployee($params);
     break;
     default:
     $empCls->getEmployees($params);
     return;
    }

    class Employee {
    protected $conn;
    protected $data = array();
    function __construct($connString) {
        $this->conn = $connString;
    }

    public function getEmployees($params) {

        $this->data = $this->getRecords($params);

        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
    function insertEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `employee` (employee_name, employee_salary) VALUES('" . $params["name"] . "', '" . $params["salary"] . "' );  ";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to insert employee data");

    }


    function getRecords($params) {
        $rp = isset($params['rowCount']) ? $params['rowCount'] : 10;

        if (isset($params['current'])) { $page  = $params['current']; } else { $page=1; };  
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $rp;

        $sql = $sqlRec = $sqlTot = $where = '';

        if( !empty($params['searchPhrase']) ) {   
            $where .=" WHERE ";
            $where .=" ( employee_name LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";    


            $where .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";
       }
       if( !empty($params['sort']) ) {  
            $where .=" ORDER By ".key($params['sort']) .' '.current($params['sort'])." ";
        }
       // getting total number records without any search
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";
        $sqlTot .= $sql;
        $sqlRec .= $sql;

        //concatenate search sql if value exist
        if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

            $sqlTot .= $where;
            $sqlRec .= $where;
        }
        if ($rp!=-1)
        $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;


        $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot employees data");
        $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) { 
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $json_data = array(
            "current"            => intval($params['current']), 
            "rowCount"            => 10,            
            "total"    => intval($qtot->num_rows),
            "rows"            => $data   // total data array
            );

        return $json_data;
    }
    function updateEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "Update `employee` set employee_name = '" . $params["edit_name"] . "', employee_salary='" . $params["edit_salary"]."'  WHERE id='".$_POST["edit_id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to update employee data");
    }

    function deleteEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "delete from `employee` WHERE id='".$params["id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to delete employee data");
    }
}
?>
```

There is also connection.php but the connection to my database works.
I guess that the response.php expects 3 parameters (name, salary and age) but only gets two...
Please don`t hesitate to ask for more details!

Thank you in advance, 
Francis

Comment: Have you also deleted `employee_age` column from the database, or only from the code?

Comment: Turn on error reporting in php to see what the error might be.

Comment: @VasilyYudin now I deleted it from the DB too and it works :D

Comment: @Francis great! Explained why this happened in an answer. Please, accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just had to delete the field from your database. It was likely marked as `NOT NULL`, and when you removed the field from the code, `INSERT` failed trying to insert a null `employee_age` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use your browsers developer tools to check the 'Network' tab for the XHR requests that get fired and have a look at the responses of those.
I think you can debug your way to a working solution from there.

You can use other tools like postman to test you AJAX "API" (response.php) but the developer tools of your browser should be more then sufficient for this ;)